# ReactJS: Adding event listeners to the HTML body element and using component's state from within those listeners

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following problem:
I have a React function component that has some state:

`const [state, setState] = React.useState({products: []})`

The products collection is loaded from a database using a useEffect hook:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   db.products.toArray((result) => setState(prevState => ({...prevState, products: result})))
}, [])
```

I want to modify the products collection whenever certain keys are pressed, but I need my component to get key inputs even if some other components are used/focused. So I decided to add an event listener to the HTML body element using:
`document.body.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown)`

But here a problem arises for me. This event listener doesn't see the state properly. It doesn't see the collection loaded from the database, but only the empty array used in the state initialization. I have found a workaround. If I replace useState with useRef it works, but I find this solution ugly and artificial because changing variables created by useRef doesn't refresh the view, so I have to refresh it explicitly.
Am I doing things the right way or is there a more "organic" way to implement a document.body event listener in a way so it would be able to use the component's state?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: doesn't sound very clear as to what is exactly happening. Are you sure that the state is updated from db before the event listener is called? where exactly are you adding the event listener?

Comment: event listeners may also be needed to add again on state change 
`React.useEffect(() => {document.body.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown)}, [products])`

Comment: Thank you sir. That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @SubhamDey won't that add new event listener handling function with every state change. It may work, but I checked there were many many added event keydown event listeners in the dev inspectors, aren't there workarounds?!!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach and define your event listener from within your useEffect hook.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    db.products.toArray((result) => setState(prevState => ({...prevState, products: result})))
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        // Your state variables should be in scope here
        setState(prevState => ({...prevState, key: event.key}))
    })
}, [])
```